# multi-dim monte carlo integration -- some complicated integration

Tags: monte-carlo, numerical-integration

I want to integrate 
$$I= \int^1_0 \int^1_0 \frac{g(x,y)}{\int^1_0 h(x,y)\,dx} \,dx\,dy. $$

For now, I sampled $n \times n$ simulation samples from $unif[0,1]$ and estimate

$$\hat{I} = n^{-2}\sum_{j} \sum_{i} \frac{g(x_i,y_j)}{\sum_i h(x_i,y_j)}.$$

Doing so gives me an answer, but I think it is too inefficient -- cannot choose large $n$. Becuase of complexity of my problem, I am choosing $n= 50$, but I guess it is too small samples to reasonably appraoximate the integration and even with $n=50$ program is too slow. I hope to know if there is any other way to estimate the integration in a better way.

Comment: Usually, efficiency is achieved by exploiting special properties of the functions, but since you frame your question in complete generality, you eliminate those possibilities.  Consider, therefore, providing some more detailed information about the nature of your $g$ and $h.$

Comment: @whuber $g$ and $h$ are derived from ranked-order model and I cannot use nice logit model because of some restrictions. So I don't think there could be any place possibilities I guess.

Comment: One approach for a quick and precise solution is to approximate $g$ and $h$ and then use these approximations for the integration. But to do this you need to know more about those functions. Are they differentiable, are they from some parametric family and so on.